# Map a list within an embeddable class object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

How do I have to map a List within a TreeMap contained i a embeddable object?

I'm trying to give an example, though it does not make that much sense. But you get my problem:

```
@Embeddable
class BookStore {

    Map<BookType, List<Order>> orders = new TreeMap<BookType, List<Order>>();
}
```

Results:

```
@OneToMany: targeting an unmapped class List<Order>.
@ElementCollection: HibernateMappingException: could not determine type for: java.util.List
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible. The best i can think of is having a private collection `List<BookTypeOrder>` and have map like methods `List<Order> getOrder(BookType b)` and `void addOrder(BookType b, Order o)` which use the internal collection to group the results